# Sync'd Hashtable not PowerShell display-friendly. Try: [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})

Tags: powershell, hashtable, synchronized

I have an object coming from .Net that has a property of type SyncHashTable that can't be viewed w/o an exception being thrown.

One-line repro:

```
[HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})
```

Multi-line easier to play with repro:

```
$ht = new-object hashtable
$ht.add("foo", "bar")
$hts = [Hashtable]::Synchronized($ht)
$hts
```

The error:

```
format-default : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

Anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got word back from Microsoft that this can be made to work:

```
PS> $r = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
PS> $r|format-table -expand coreonly -autoSize

Count IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized SyncRoot      Keys Values
----- ---------- ----------- -------------- --------      ---- ------
    0      False       False           True System.Object {}   {}

PS> $r.Add("key","value")
PS> $r["key"]
value
```

Apparently it is a bug in the way the type is formatted for display.

Comment: BTW, if you want, vote on the bug here - https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/615449/display-of-synchronized-hashtable-generates-error